# Find the same numbers between [a,b] intervals

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose I have 3 array of consecutive numbers

```cpp
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]
c = [3, 4]
```

Then the same number that appears in all 3 arrays is 3.
My algorithm is to use two `for` loops in each other to check for the same array and push it in another array (let's call it `d`). Then

```cpp
d = [2, 3] (d = a overlap b)
```

And use it again to check for array `d` and `c` => The final result is 1, cause there are only 1 numbers that appears in all 3 arrays.

```
e = [3] (e = c overlap d) => e.length = 1
```

Other than that, if there exists only 1 array, then the algo should return the length of the array, as all of its numbers appear in itself. But I think my said algo above would take too long because the numbers of array can go up to 10^5. So, any idea of a better algorithm?

Comment: `2` does not appear in `c`?

Comment: You can calculate the maximum of the first item of the arrays, and the minimum of the last elements of the array. That is the range of numbers in all lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I think my said algo above would take too long because the numbers of array can go up to 10<sup>5</sup>. So, any idea of a better algorithm?

Yes, since these are ranges, you basically want to calculate the intersection of the ranges. This means that you can calculate the maximum *m* of all the *first* elements of the lists, and the minimum *n* of all the *last* elements of the list. All the numbers between *m* and *n* (both inclusive) are then members of all lists. If *m>n*, then there are no numbers in these lists.

You do not need to calculate the overlap by enumerating over the first list, and check if these are members of the last list. Since these are consecutive numbers, we can easily find out what the overlap is.

In short, the overlap of *[a, ..., b]* and *[c, ..., d]* is *[* max(*a*,*c*), ..., min(*b*,*d*) *]*, there is no need to check the elements in between.